# JQuery + ExtJS: how to process one DIV component by using these two libs

Tags: jquery, html, extjs, draw, flot

I am doing a simple project targeting at online graph drawing. I am using Flot/JQuery library to draw graphs, using ExtJs for layout.

What I try to do is as follows:
1. define a DIV 
2. using Flot functions to draw graphs in this DIV
3. put this DIV in a panel defined by ExtJs code

my question is:

how to control the sequence that first call Flot functions to draw in DIV, and then to put this DIV with graphs into the panel by ExtJS?

Now, the DIV and graphs cant be displayed on the page.

any

Comment: Extjs 4 does graphs, doesn't it?

Comment: yes. but i just found that Flot has all the features i want, am not sure whether ExtJs graph can do the same work.

Comment: I _think_ extjs 4 uses raphael for charting, you should be able to do a lot of things with that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1` and `3` can be accomplished by using [`Ext.Panel#html`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#cfg-Ext.Component-html)

`2` is a matter of adding the graph rendering code to the [`afterlayout`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Container.html#event-Ext.Container-afterlayout) event.

Comment: I don't know anything about ExtJS, but the only gotcha with flot is that the div has to have a width/height, made most likely by having it attached to the DOM and visible.

Comment: Good point, the panel's div could have zero width/height for a variety of reasons. You could either figure out the ways that could happen and listen for those ext events, or (I'm pretty sure) flot throws an error  when it tries to render into a zero width/height element. Maybe set a timeout to try and plot again in 500ms or some such?

Comment: i used firebug to see the output html generated by ExtJS code. found out that I can use the "body" part of each panel as the space for plotting, since it has the width and height. for example, i defined a panel named "pn1", i can see the associated div "id=pn1". belongs to this DIV node, in the deepest node there is a ChildDIV with the class "class=x-panel-body", however its ID "ext-gen-20" is generated by ExtJS dynamically. So in this situation, can I use the class type "X-panel-body" and use the parent DIV "pn1" together to execute query and finally get access to this body DIV "ext-gen-20"?